# Transitive closure of a reflexive antisymmetric relation

Tags: relations

Prove that the transitive closure $S$ of a reflexive antisymmetric relation $R$ is a partial order.

Comment: Yes, this is obvious. We know the transitive closure must be transitive and reflexive as given, but the hard part is proving that it is antisymmetric. Can you help?

Answer (score 6):

The conjecture is false.

Let $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and let $R = \{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(1,2),(2,3),(3,1)\}$ which is reflexive and antisymmetric.

Its transitive closure, S = $\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(1,2),(2,3),(3,1),(1,3),(2,1), (3,2)\}$, however is not antisymmetric since $(2,1)\in S$ and $(1,2)\in S$ but $1\neq 2$ and thus can't be a partial order.

Comment: @amWhy $R$ is not transitive since $(1,2) \in R$ and $(2,3)\in R$ but $(1,3)\not\in R$.

Comment: You're correct. Missed that pair.

Comment: Thanks Alraxite for your counter example that answers my question.